# Dead-ends are connected by osm2pgrouting

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I've downloaded an extent of OSM data with QGIS's OpenStreetMap downloader, and want to use this data for with pgRouting. I can load it without problems as:

```
osm2pgrouting --f data.osm --conf mapconfig.xml --dbname db --username user --schema osm --clean
```

However, as you can see in the picture, the many of the dead-ends get connected to some seemingly random vertices. These dead-ends were created by cutting the OSM data with the extent polygon.

I'm using osm2pgrouting 2.3.2

Any tips on how to import OSM data cleanly?

[image]

Comment: Which version of osm2pgrouting are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Balazs,

I've never used QGIS before for downloading OSM data so not sure if it does anything special.  Also I'm not sure what area you are downloading to be able to replicate.

Can you try using overpass api instead to download your area of interest and then use the osm file in osm2pgrouting.  This is documented in worksop 
http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.4.11/en/chapters/prepare_data.html#option-3-download-using-overpass-xapi

so your command would look something like below which you call from commandline:

```
wget --progress=dot:mega -O sample.osm "http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[bbox=-71.16528,42.31628,-70.99396,42.39493][@meta]"
```

If you still have issue, post the overpass command you are using.

Comment: BTW: XAPI is seriously outdated these days, the workshop material really needs an overhaul. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Xapi

Comment: The workshop material is to be used with OSGeoLive Disk on a virtual machine, it has the xapi example for people that don't have the VM and have all the software that OSGeoLive provides installed in their own computer but lacks the data.

Comment: Downloading additional data is not the issue, but using XAPI is (at least in the long run). Better go to openstreetmap.org, hit the "Export" button, select your area, and click on the "Overpass API" download link. That download link (e.g. http://overpass-api.de/api/map?bbox=7.43934,51.06231,7.46305,51.07082) should be included in the workshop material instead of the XAPI link.

Answer (score 0):

I do have exactly the same issues as described by Balazs with the following setup:

- PostgreSQL 10.3
- PostGIS 2.4.4.
- pgrouting 2.6.0
- osm2pgrouting 2.3.3
- Ubuntu 18.04

And following mapconfig.xml file:

https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting/blob/master/mapconfig.xml

The data is originating from an osm.pbf-file and was downloaded from Geodatenfabrik. Are there any recommendations? If possible I want to use the listed versions of the software.